# using latest() with pagination causes TypeError unhashable type: 'slice'

Tags: django

Perhaps my approach/query is totally wrong but anyway, I am trying to list books and the latest edit that was made to them. A book can be edited multiple times and each edit has a category.

```
     Book(models.Model)


     BookEdit(models.Model):
        book=models.ForeignKey(Book,related_name='book_edits')
        editedon=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        action=models.CharField(max_length=250
```

Now in my views I am simply doing:

```
      books=Book.objects.value('id','book_edits__action').latest('book_edits__editedon')

            try:
                page=request.query_params.get('page',1)
                paginator=Paginator(books,20)
                data=paginator.page(page)
            except PageNotAnInteger:
                data=paginator.page(1)
            except EmptyPage:
                data=paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
```

I have noticed it works without latest(), which seems to output dictionary object. How can I use latest() with paginator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`latest()` returns a single object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#latest), not a queryset. So it doesn't make sense to try and paginate it.

It seems like you want to annotate your results with the latest edit date. You need to use [an annotation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset) to do that. Something like:

```
from django.db.models import Max

Book.objects.annotate(last_edit=Max('book_edits__editedon'))
```

which will then add a `last_edit` property to each object in your queryset, corresponding to the most recent edit for it.

Comment: Oh thanks. I must have missed the 'returns single object' thing in the documentation. Thanks!